# Integer array size in C without using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, size

I need to declare an array of structures with size `symbolnum`, but because `symbolnum` is variable C will produce an error when i write the following code:

```
extern int symbolnum;

struct SymbTab stab[symbolnum];
```

I already tried:

```
extern int symbolnum;
const int size = symbolnum;
struct SymTab stab[size];
```

Is there a way to achieve this without using dynamic memory allocation functions like `malloc()` or initializing the size of array using a very big number?

Comment: What's wrong with using `malloc`?

Comment: is `stab` a global or rather a local variable?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't want to use `malloc` because the array size will be known aand static  after the lexical analysis is over.

Comment: @notthatbad so you need to tell us more about your _actual_ problem. Who defines the content of `symbolnum` and when?

Comment: @Jabberwocky `symbolnum` is the number of identifiers that flex will find in a given code and I am trying to implement a table of these identifiers in my syntax analysis.

Comment: @notthatbad So does this mean the source file containing `stab` is created with an initializer at build time?

Comment: Another approach : declare `struct SymbTab stab[1024];` and add runtime checks in your program to be sure that you have less than 1024 symbols.

Comment: I think the very first comment here asks a very good question.  if after answering that honestly, and you've determined that the constraints as described are necessary, the path forward requires use of VLA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of global arrays *must* be fixed at compile time.  VLAs are only allowed inside of functions.

If the value of `symbolnum` isn't known until runtime, you'll need to declare `stab` as a pointer type and allocate memory for it dynamically.

Alternately, if the array doesn't take up more than a few 10s of KB, you can define the VLA in the `main` function and set a global pointer to it.

Comment: Thanks. What if I declare the array in main?

Comment: It's rather a problem that having VLA at file scope level would require evaluating a size expression at file scope. This contradicts one of basis principles of C. "No code execution outside of `main()`"

Comment: @notthatbad You could declare the VLA in `main` then have a global pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

C11 and later permit variable-length arrays as an optional feature.  C99 permitted them as a mandatory feature.  However, in no case are VLAs permitted at file scope, which appears to be what you are trying to achieve.

And file-scope VLAs wouldn't make sense in light of C semantics anyway.  Objects declared at file scope have static storage duration, meaning that they come into existence at or before the beginning of program execution, and live until program termination.  That means the array length is needed before the variable can take anything other than its initial value (which is zero or an integer constant expression), so one might as well just use that initial value directly.

Additionally, some C implementations (notably MSVC) never implemented VLAs even when C99 was the current standard, and have no intention to do so now that the feature is optional in the current standard.

So,

> Is there a way to achieve this without using dynamic memory allocation
> functions like `malloc()` or initializing the size of array using a very
> big number?

It depends a bit on your exact needs (and on your C implementation), but likely not.  One possibility would be to use a local VLA in `main()`, or in some other function whose execution encompasses the whole need for the array.  If your C implementation supports it them you could declare a VLA there, and pass around a pointer to that.  But note well that if the upper bound on the number of elements you need is really "a very large number" then this is unlikely to be suitable.  VLAs are typically allocated on the stack, which puts a relatively tight bound on how large they can be.

Comment: The one compelling constraint you mention in whether or not to use VLA is limitation of stack memory, but in most development environments the size of the stack can be changed to meet design constraints.  Wouldn't that mitigate the stack problem in your mind?

Comment: @rykker, only if an appropriate bound on the needed number of elements can be chosen at compile time, so that an adequate amount of stack can be ensured.  But then it is easier, more portable, and semantically similar to just declare the array as an ordinary one with whatever upper-bound size you want.

Comment: @JohnBollinger *only if an appropriate bound on the needed number of elements can be chosen at compile time*  How does that not apply also to memory obtained from `malloc()` *et al*?  If you oversubscribe your resources, you fail. If you don't know the limits, you're coding blind. Given the memory-overallocation model usually used on Linux, at least using stack memory fails immediately, as opposed to "Oh, you dared to actually **use** the memory I said you can have?!?! **I LIED!! It's `SIGKILL` for you!  BWAAHAAAHAA!!**" and your customer wonders why the process died 11 days after starting it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, in the VLA case, the number of elements that can be accommodated is approximately a parameter of the binary, in that rykker proposes to accommodate it by setting an acceptable stack size via the development tools.  With `malloc()`, the number of elements that can be accommodated is instead a property of the execution environment.  I suppose there scenarios that would favor each of those.  But if you are contemplating compile-time provision of the needed space, then again, why go the arcane route of twiddling stack size instead of just declaring a max-size array?

Comment: @JohnBollinger The stack size is only a compile-time parameter for the process's initial thread.  The stack size for every other thread on both Windows and POSIX systems is a run-time parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Is there a way to achieve this without using dynamic memory allocation functions like malloc() or initializing the size of array
> using a very big number?"*

If you can use [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLA), then yes it can be done.  The following illustrates one way...

With a `struct` definition in global space, (eg, top of .c file, or in .h file) *local* array instances of that `struct` can be created using a VLA, keeping in mind the stipulations mentioned in the link for using VLA.  The VLA `struct` array can then be passed as a function parameter, to either be used in the called function, or to be updated and returned, just as any other function parameter is used. Here is a simple example:

```
//define either at top of .c file in file global space
//or in a header file that is included in any .c.  Then
//the typedef num_s can be used to create instances where needed
//
typedef struct SymbTab{
    int iVal;
    double dVal;
} SymbTab_s;

void populate_struct(size_t symbolnum, SymbTab_s *stab);

int main(void)
{
    size_t symbolnum = 0;//(using size_t). note, as you describe, this 
                         //comes after flex analysis normally, but for 
                         //this demo user input is used for simple 
                         // example of dynamically sizing array.
    printf("Enter symbolnum of struct array:\n");
    scanf("%zu", &symbolnum);
    SymbTab_s stab[symbolnum]; //dynamically sized array of SymbTab_s
    memset(stab, 0, sizeof(SymbTab_s) * symbolnum); //initialize new array
    populate_struct(symbolnum,  stab); //pass as function argument and update values
    //demo updated values
    for(int i=0; i < symbolnum; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, %lf\n", stab[i].iVal, stab[i].dVal);
    }
    return 0;
}

//simple function to demo form of parameters
//note size parameter is passed first
void populate_struct(size_t symbolnum, SymbTab_s *stab)
{
   for(int i=0; i < symbolnum; i++)
   {
       stab[i].iVal = i;
       stab[i].dVal = 1.0*i;
   }
}
```